# Kusto Query Language - Microsoft Defender

Tags: windows-defender

I am trying to create a custom query on Microsoft defender advanced hunting platform that scan the device for a specific extension.

I tried these queries:

- `DeviceFileEvents | where FileName endswith ".xxx"`
- `DeviceFileEvents | where FileName like @".xxx"`
- `DeviceFileEvents | where FileName contains "*.xxx"`

Am i missing something?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The three queries above are not equivalent, this one matches the semantic that you describe and has the best performance, so if it does not return the result you expect please add an example value for the `FileName`:

```
DeviceFileEvents | where FileName endswith ".xxx"
```

The "like" operator is an alias for the "contains" operator and it looks for the string you provided (`".xxx"`) anywhere within the text. This means that the semantic is not what you are looking for and the following query has much lower perf:

```
DeviceFileEvents | where FileName like @".xxx"
```

Finally, the last option is searching for a string that has the char sequence of `"*.xxx"` (`"*"` does not have any special meaning in this context) anywhere in the `FileName` column, this definitely does not have the semantic that you are looking for and the contains operator performs much worse than the "`endswith`" operator:

```
DeviceFileEvents | where FileName contains "*.xxx"
```